# how to calculate days difference of vaules in same column?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

I have data like this:

```
select * from date_table;
 startdate
2018-08-22
2018-08-24
2018-08-27
2018-08-29
2018-08-31
2018-09-05
2018-09-07
2018-09-10
```

I have written this query, which only gives days difference

```
CREATE temporary TABLE if not exists results AS (
select t.startdate, datediff( 
(select min(t1.startdate) 
from 
date_table t1 where
 t1.startdate>t.startdate),
t.startdate ) days_diff 
from 
date_table t) ;

select * from results:
```

Above query gives result as:

```
startdate   days_diff 
2018-08-22    2
2018-08-24    3
2018-08-27    2
2018-08-29    2
2018-08-31    5
2018-09-05    2
2018-09-07    3  
2018-09-10
```

But I want result like:

```
startdate     enddate      days_diff 
2018-08-22   2018-08-24      2
2018-08-27   2018-08-29      2
2018-08-31   2018-09-05      5
2018-09-07   2018-09-10      3
```

I'm using MySQL(version 5.6). Kindly let me know if there is any solution for this problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Impossible now. The records have no attributes which allows to distinguish what is start and what is finish.

Comment: Of course you may enumerate records (use user-defined variable) and distinguish by even-odd... in this case group by `number-1 MOD 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to want to enumerate the rows and then aggregate.  In pre-8.0 versions, you can use variables.  The rest is then aggregation:

```
select min(start_date) as start_date, max(start_date) as end_date
from (select (@rn := @rn + 1) as seqnum, t.*
      from (select t.* from date_table t order by start_date) t cross join
           (select @rn := 0) params
     ) t
group by floor((seqnum - 1) / 2);
```

Comment: Thank you. This Worked for me.